# Connect to cassandra on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-app-engine, cassandra

I deployed a Cassandra cluster through their launcher: https://cloud.google.com/launcher/explore?q=cassandra

I can connect to the VM fine, through SSH/PuTTY.

Then when I try to connect with for example `DBeaver` I get:

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableExeption: All host(s) tried for query failed(tried: /x.x.x.x:9160)
com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionExption:[/x.x.x.x:9160] Unexpected error during transport initialization. Connection has been closed`

Or with `cassandra-driver` (nodejs), I get:

`All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, x.x.x.x:9160: Error: read ECONNRESET. See innerErrors. 
InnerErrors: { 'x.x.x.x:9160': { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } } 
Info: Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver.`

I've forwarded the `9160` port in the google developer console and it seems to work because when I stop the cassandra server on the VM it gives a different error, indicating connection is refused:

`All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, x.x.x.x:9160: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED. See innerErrors.
InnerErrors:  { 'x.x.x.x:9160':
   { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect' } }
Info:  Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver.`

Now, I've tried editing the `cassandra.yaml` `rcp_adress` to the actual `external` address instead of `0.0.0.0`.
I've also tried the `internal` serverfarm address.

I've not changed the default authentication (but also tried with auth):

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
# authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator

authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
# authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
```

I'm at a loss, the connection seems to work, but cassandra seems to not allow a login or reset the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect on the thrift port (9160).  You should be using the native protocol port (9042).